# Navbar content loading all options

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a navbar in Jquery mobile which have 5 contents, each content have a text right now. The problem is that the first time that I load the page, in the first tab all the content is loaded, and as soon as you start pressing the buttons, the content is loaded normally, as shown in the image below:

[image: Image 1]

Then when I start clicking the buttons the content shows correctly:

[image: Image 2]

Below is the code that I'm using:

Javascript:

```
<script>

(function($) {

// Before handling a page change...
$(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function(e, data)
{
    // If the new page is not being loaded by URL, bail
    if (typeof data.toPage !== "string")
    {
        return;
    }

    // If the new page has a corresponding navbar link, activate its content div
    var url = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(data.toPage);
    var $a = $("div[data-role='navbar'] a[href='" + url.hash + "']");
    if ($a.length)
    {
        // Suppress normal page change handling since we're handling it here for this case
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    // If the new page has a navbar, activate the content div for its active item
    else
    {
        $a = $(url.hash + " div[data-role='navbar']").find("a.ui-btn-active");

        // Allow normal page change handling to continue in this case so the new page finishes rendering
    }

    // Show the content div to be activated and hide other content divs for this page
    var $content = $($a.attr("href"));
    $content.siblings().hide();
    $content.show();
});

})(jQuery);
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>

  <div data-role="page">
   <div data-role="header">
     <div data-role="navbar">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#oneContent" class="ui-btn-active ui-btn-persist">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#twoContent">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#threeContent">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fourContent">Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fiveContent">Five</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
<center>
         <div data-role="content">
       <div id="oneContent">First</div>
       <div id="twoContent">Second</div>
       <div id="threeContent">Third</div>
       <div id="fourContent">Fourth</div>
       <div id="fiveContent">Fifth</div>
   </div>
   </center>
   </div>

</body>
```

How can avoid the problem of loading all content at first load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UPDATED TO ANSWER NEW REQUEST BELOW

*If you want the first tab to show up by default, set the CSS of them all individually then toggle them into view.*

**First** put this in your `<head>` or in a linked **CSS** file:

```
<style>[data-role=content] > div { display: none; }</style>
```

**Then** insert these two lines into your **Javascript** at the beginning like so:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var path = (window.location.hash) ? window.location.hash : '#oneContent';
        $(path).show();
    });
    $(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {
    ....
```

### [Here's an updated fiddle diddle skittle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExALt/1/)

Comment: Thanks, its almost what I needed, do you know how to display the content of the first tab when the page is loaded?

Comment: Adjusted to fit your new constraints.  Hope this helps :) I removed my original answer in favor of this one since it's more versatile and logical.

Comment: Thanks, but its not working, I wrapped everything in a single html, and it doesnt load the first option by default. Also, when other buttons are selected, they turn white instead the original blue that they have. I copied everything in head, script and html and the issue is still there.

Comment: I make it work adding a $( document ).ready(function(){}, and inside that function call the first element in the navbar. Please make the corrections needed so I can vote up your answer (which helped me a lot).

Comment: haha thats so weird I had every intention of doing that before posting this reply and somehow I got distracted and forgot sorry about that.  I'm glad you found the answer I left out!  I fixed my answer for you (and the fiddle).  Glad to help :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help :) I marked your answer as valid.